# Would Like to Create an XML Feed From Classifieds Content

Tags: xml, html, rss

I have a classifieds where a visitor can list their vehicle by completing simple fields which then places this info (year, Make, Model, Engine, Seats, VIN) in a DB to be displayed on my website.

Now I want to share this info with a partnering site via an XML feed but everything I come up with has to do with READING an XML file into a site. I want to be the one CREATING this XML file for others to read in.

I've read all about this in W3Schools tutorials but those just haven't enabled me to do what I'm trying to do.

Suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's your server platform, sql and programming language?

Comment: Sorry, PHP and MySql. (I hope this is the correct answer)

Comment: That helps. I'll post an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way to do this in php is to read your data from SQL into an array and then use the XML writer object to serialize the array into an XML stream. The other (simple, but dirty) method is to read the data from your DB and simply output the XML as string data with printf. I often use the dirty way because it's easy and uses less server resources. Here's some bits to get you started:

```
// Set the HTTP header content type to XML
header( "Content-Type: text/xml", true );
// Output the XML tag
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
// Output a root XML element
echo "<car_list>\n";
```

Fetch your data from mysql in the usual way and then loop through it outputting a car element for each one:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($Result) ) {
  echo sprintf( "  <car make=\"%s\" model=\"%s\" />\n", $row['make'], $row['model'] );
}
```

Finally output the closing tag for the root element:

```
echo "</car_list>\n";
```

This should output something like:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<car_list>
  <car make="BMW' model="328i" />
  <car make="GMC" model="Jimmy" />
</car_list>
```

Here the data are all carried in XML attributes which seems appropriate for your application. Of course you could generate subelements by not leaving the car tag open, output those elements and then a  element.

Comment: Hi again @bitfiddler, Thanks so much for this. This is a HUGE help but it will likely take me a few days to be able to sort through it all as even the php you included may seem like second nature to alot of you, to me, alot of it's still a mystery but I thank you immensely for your help.

Comment: Haven't forgotten about this... Will be working on it soon  (and likely needing help) but Thanks for the help!!